# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, keytool

I am new to SSL.

I am trying to create keystore for SSL connection using keytool. First I tried the following command

```
[aniket@localhost bin]$ keytool -genkey -alias myKeyStore -keyalg RSA -keystore
/home/aniket/keystore
```

It asked me password and other details and finally gave me following error

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/aniket/keystore 
(Is a directory)
```

So I created a file keystoreFile.txt inside keystore folder and executed

```
[aniket@localhost bin]$ keytool -genkey -alias myKeyStore -keyalg RSA -keystore
/home/aniket/keystore/keystoreFile.txt
```

and now(no prompt for password etc) I am getting

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty:
/home/aniket/keystore/keystoreFile.tx
```

What should be the contents of the file. I though keytool will generate key pair (a public key and associated private

Comment: Keystores aren't text files. Don't use the .txt extension for things that aren't text.

Comment: @EJP yeah changed it to keystoreFile.jks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Delete the empty keystoreFile.txt, then run your 2nd command again

```
[aniket@localhost bin]$ keytool -genkey -alias myKeyStore -keyalg RSA -keystore
/home/aniket/keystore/keystoreFile.txt
```

It's trying to **create** the file you specify with the `-keystore` flag. The reason your first one command failed is that you gave it an existing directory name.